# Should I say "at both single- and multiple-object levels"

Tags: american-english, writing

In my current writing task, there are two different conceptual levels: one single object level and one multiple objects level. When I call them together, should I say:

"At both single- and multiple-object levels..."

Or,

"At both single and multiple objects levels"?

Comment: Either, though I would say "single-object and multi-object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is a correct usage of hyphens. In my opinion, this is the better way to render the sentence..

The second would be understood the same way (although you do need to drop the "s" from "objects").